# Counting inputs in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

The variable "countT" keeps adding after every input, even with the if statement that says to add 0 to "countT" it continues to do so. I tried doing, if  temp <= 0: then it would also add nothing to "countT".

```
countT = 0
temp = 0
listT = []

breath = input("Do you have shortness of breath (y/n)? ")
cough = input("Do you have a cough(y/n)? ")
sorethroat_runnynose = input("Do you have a sore throat/runny nose (y/n)? ")
nausea = input("Do you have diarrhea, nausea and vomiting (y/n)? ")

if str.lower(breath)== 'y' and str.lower(cough)== 'y'and str.lower(sorethroat_runnynose)== 'n' and str.lower(nausea)== 'n':
    print("Enter 5 most recent temperature readings:")
    for x in range (1,6):
        temp2= int(input("Temp: "))
        temp += temp2
        listT.append(temp2)
        if temp == 0:
            countT +=0
        else:
            countT +=1

    avgT = (temp/countT) 

    print("Your max Temp was: ",(max(listT)))
    print("Average Temp is: ",avgT)
    print("You likely have the influenza virus")

    if avgT > 100 and temp > max(listT):
       print("Please seek medical attention now!") 

    elif avgT > 99:
        print("Monitor your condition closely!")

elif str.lower(breath)== 'n' and str.lower(cough)== 'n' and str.lower(sorethroat_runnynose)== 'n' and str.lower(nausea)== 'n':
    print("There are no symptoms but you should wait to see if you develop any.")

else:
    print("you likely have the influenza virus.")
```

Comment: The condition should be `if temp2 == 0` instead of `temp`. `temp` is your cumulative sum

Comment: Also you don't really need that if condition to add 0. Just add 1 `if temp2 > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question what I understood is that you want to add 1 to `countT` if the current input is not 0. The reason it is not working correctly now is that you are checking `temp` in `if temp == 0:` statement although you should check `temp2` because `temp2` is the input and `temp` is the sum of inputs.
Furthermore, you can write the whole check in one if statement (without else) like below:

```
if temp != 0:
    countT +=1
```

or if you also want to eliminate negative inputs:

```
if temp > 0:
    countT +=1
```